# Ruby gem for monitoring HTTP calls by other gems?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I remember seeing a gem of this description on GitHub, but now I can't find it.

The idea was that it would let you see the actual API calls / service endpoints that other gems were using to do their magic.

I don't remember if it was specifically for HTTP or what.

Comment: Found it: https://github.com/railsware/http_logger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know that gem, but you could recreate that functionality quite easily by opening up ruby's Net::HTTP class, aliasing existing methods and adding some logging calls before the actual HTTP calls.

For example, here's how you could print calls to GET to stdout:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'net/http'

class Net::HTTP
  # Note that you have to be in the singleton class to alias a class method  
  class << self
    alias_method :orig_get, :get

    def get(uri_or_host, path=nil, port=nil)
      # here's where you log theactivity, before calling the original method
      puts "GET: #{uri_or_host}#{':' + port if port}#{path}"
      orig_get(uri_or_host, path, port)
    end
  end
end
```